Как удвоить все гласные в слове?
Я недавно начал заниматься программированием, но я не знаю как удвоить все гласные в слове без многократного использования метода find.
Например, с помощью алгоритма из слова "апельсины" сделать слово "аапеельсииныы".
Поможете?

Чётко опишите стоящую перед вами задачу. Приведите примеры входных и выходных данных. И всё это прямо в вопросе.

X = "апельсины"

Что вам нужно сделать — найти все гласные в слове или "умножить"(??) их? Поставьте задачу корректнее

Найти гласные и из умножить на 2 пример (аалиивкаа)

tio.run
import re

s = "У меня установлен Windows"

print(re.sub('([ёуеыаоэяиюeyuioaЁУЕЫАОЭЯИЮEYUIOA])', r'\1\1', s))

или так tio.run:
import re

s = "У меня установлен Windows"

print(re.sub('([ёуеыаоэяиюeyuioa])', r'\1\1', s, flags=re.I))

УУ мееняя уустааноовлеен Wiindoows


Может лучше добавить флаг re.IGNORECASE чтобы не перебирать заглавные гласные?

@dofi4ka, может я криворукий, но у меня не работает: У мееняя установлен Windows.

@dofi4ka, а, разобрался: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8813281/4928642.

Какие-то еретические методы, конечно, выше рассказывают. Можно попроще, без всяких регулярных выражений, кэйсфолдов и ос... Полезно, конечно, разобраться, но тебе, как новичку, это на пользу не пойдёт пока что.
s=input() #ввод строки
str_of_vowel_letters='аеёиоуыэюя' #строка с гласными буквами в нижнем регистре
s2='' # пустая строка, в которой мы соберём новое слово
for i in s:
    if i.lower() in str_of_vowel_letters: 
"""
метод lower превращает букву из введённой строки в букву нижнего регистра, нам бы не пригодился этот метод, если бы мы в строку с гласными буквами нижнего регистра добавили гласные буквы в верхнем регистре
"""
        s2+=2*i
    else:
        s2+=i
print(s2)


Готовый скрипт для тестирования:
import os

print("-" * 50 + "\nУдвоение гласных в строке (для трёх языков):\n" + "-" * 50)

v_text = "«Ой, у лузі червона калина похилилася...»"
lst_vowels = "аеєиіїоуюяёыэaeiou"

print("\nИсходный текст:", v_text)
print("Текст с удвоенными гласными:", ''.join([char * 2 if char.lower() in lst_vowels else char for char in v_text]))

print("\nНажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...")
os.system("pause > nul" if os.name == "nt" else "read > /dev/null")


Вот простенький код:
мы вводим слово и создаем пустую строку, в которую будем записывать итог.
Также создаем строку со всеми гласными.
Затем циклом идем по всем буквам строки, добавляем их в новую и если это гласная, то добавляем еще раз :)
word = input()
new_word = ''
vowels = 'УЕЫАОЭЯИЮЁуеыаоэяиюё'

for char in word:
    new_word += char
    if char in vowels:
        new_word += char
print(new_word)


Вот достаточно простой способ
text = input()  # строчка над которой будем издеваться
vowels = "аоэеиыуёюя".lower()  # символы которые будем дублировать

new_text = ""  # создаем новую строчку куда посимвольно запишем изменённый текст с продублированными гласными
for char in text:  # проходимся по всем символам изначальной строчки
    if char.lower() in vowels:  # если символ есть в строчке с гласными
        new_text += char * 2  # добавляем два этих символа
        # умножение символа (строчки) дублриует её n раз
        # "а" * 2 -> "аа"
    else:  # иначе
        new_text += char  # добавляем символ без изменений

print(new_text)

>>> апельсины
аапеельсииныы


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Эм.. Из-за in text.casefold() весь результат будет в нижнем регистре, а исходя из вопроса я бы ожидал сохранение регистра.

@Qwertiy я поторопился немного, не туда влепил его, вот теперь нормально

Мне кажется, такое его использование ничем не отличается от lower?

@Qwertiy casefold и lower грубо говоря делают одно и то же, просто lower принято использовать когда нужно сделать все символы с строке строчными, а casefold когда нужно сравнить строчки без учета регистра

Просто если там получится больше 1 символа, то, вероятно, in всё равно криво отработает?

@Qwertiy можно мою идею с casefold доработать и хранить гласные как множество, но это уже будет overingenering конкретный, согласен лучше всё таки было lower использовать

Вот тоже кажется, что можно, но не понимаю, как это правильно должно работать...

@Qwertiy casefold используется для корректного сравнения без учета регистра для всех языков. Для русского разницы не будет. Для какого-нибудь немецкого 'STRASSE'.casefold() == 'Straße'.casefold(), а сравнение с lower вместо casefold даст False. А так - да, в данном случае без разницы, что использовать.

@insolor, да, я нагуглил. Но если удваивать согласные, то 'ß'.casefold() даст 'ss', а потом 'ss' in '...qrstuvwxyz' даст false. Так что конкретно в данном коде не помогает.

@Qwertiy я применял метод casefold и к литералу с изначальными символами. Будь у нас вначале строчка типа "abcß". casefold() то она преобразовалась бы в adcss. Тогда 'ß'.casefold() in "abcss" вернул бы ожидаемый True. Проблема только в том что "s".casefold() in "abcss" тоже вернул бы уже неожидаемый True. Если уже и работать с casefold то хранить надо множество строчек а не строчку: set(map(str.casefold, "abcß")) -> {"a", "b", "c", "ss"}

@dofi4ka, когда ты применял к изначальной строке получался косяк, что то, что не меняли, отличалось бы в начальной строке и в конечной. А в последнем комментарии если ß всё равно в строке, то какой смысл её casefold'ить? Она ж и так через in найдётся?
